# \flushleft prevents first line indentation!

Tags: horizontal-alignment, indentation

I am using \flushleft to left justify a paragraph, but it removes the first line indentation. Any ideas?[image]

Comment: that is as it is designed, if you want flush left but with indentation you can used `\raggedright\parindent=15pt`  to set it back, note that `flushleft` is defigned to be used as `\begin{flushleft}` use `\raggedright` if you want a command form.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all, `flushleft` is a list environment. You should not use it as a command. Use `\raggedright` as the corresponding command.

`flushleft` and `\raggedright` set `\parindent` to 0pt. So you could get back the indent setting `\parindent`, e.g., to 1em:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{mwe}

\begin{document}
\raggedright\setlength{\parindent}{1em}
\lipsum
\end{document}
```

But the result is very ugly. Perceptibility would be better, if you'd use paragraphs with empty lines:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{parskip}
\usepackage{mwe}

\begin{document}
\raggedright
\lipsum
\end{document}
```

You may also allow hyphenation using package [`ragged2e`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/ragged2e):

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{parskip}
\usepackage{ragged2e}
\usepackage{mwe}

\begin{document}
\RaggedRight
\lipsum
\end{document}
```

[image: paragraph with skip]

Automatic indent or changing the *ragged zone* and the filling of the last line is also available:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{ragged2e}
\usepackage{mwe}

\setlength{\RaggedRightParfillskip}{.25\textwidth plus 1fil}
\setlength{\RaggedRightRightskip}{0pt plus .1\textwidth}
\setlength{\RaggedRightParindent}{1em}

\begin{document}
\RaggedRight
\lipsum
\end{document}
```

[image: paragraphs with indent]